# Convexity of Gamma function

Tags: calculus

How to prove that Gamma function is convex, I know that 
$$\Gamma''(s)=\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-x}(\ln x)^2dx.$$
How to show this $>0$?

Comment: *Hint:* every single factor in the integrand is non-negative.

Comment: Look at the sign of the integrand: $x^s$ is positive as well as the exponential and the square of the logarithm. (obviously we consider $s$ as real...

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to note that for all $x \in (0, \infty)$, the function
$\phi_x(t)= x^{t-1} e^{-x}$ is convex on $(0, \infty)$. Hence
$\Gamma(t) = \int_0^\infty \phi_x(t) dx $ is convex (this follows directly from the definition of convexity and integrating both sides).

Answer (score 2):

On $\mathbb{R}^+$, the $\Gamma$ function is log-convex due to the [Bohr-Mollerup theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem), hence convex.